# Cannot fetch the latest record from the database

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am trying to get the latest record from the Database (Derby database).

I have a `BILL` table in the database that has a column `BillId`. The data type of `BillId` is `varchar(15)` and is in the format as:

```
3122022-1
```

The digits before the "-" (i.e., 3122022) are according to the date (3/12/2002). The value after the "-" is the bill counter (i.e., 1).

The problem is, when I try to get the latest record from the database using `max(BILLID)`, it considers `3122022-9` as the maximum/latest record even if the billId `3122022-10` or higher exists.

In simple words, it ignores the 0 or any value placed at the second place after "-". Why is this issue happening and what is the solution??

Here is the table structure:
[Bill table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hedAM.png)

I used the following query:

```
select max(billId) as lastBill from Bill where empName='Hassan' and Date=Current Date;
```

empName is important as there are 4-5 employees and each will have their own count of Bill.

If I run this query:

```
select billid from bill order by empName desc;
```

I get this result:

[Bill ids when I sort them by empName column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6iNw.png)

But if I run the max(billId) query, This is what I get:
`select max(billId) as lastBill from Bill where empName='Hassan' and Date=Current Date;`
[max(billid) results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQZlu.png)

I hope I was able to explain my question well. Will be grateful for your help and support.

I tried `max(billId)`

Comment: This works right? `select billid from bill order by empName desc;` add a `LIMIT 1` and you have the last value...here is a good article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-select-last/

Comment: Can you provide textual data as formatted text, not as screenshots? That includes table definitions and SQL results. Also, take a look at [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/12567365). For background, also see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365).

Comment: Please share sample data and expected output. it will help for us to understand data format

Comment: "_Why is this issue happening?_" - Because values such as `3122022-9` are not numbers - they are strings and will be sorted in alphanumeric order (so, `10` comes before `9`). "_what is the solution?_" - There are probably several. One way: store the data in the database as two separate numeric fields `3122022` and `9`, if you want to sort the data numerically.

Comment: *The digits before the "-" (i.e., 3122022) are according to the date (3/12/2002).* How do you know it's not 31st February 2002? btw, to prepend 'Bill' to column names in table BILL is completely redundant

Answer (score 0):

i came up with sample dataset and query.
//Postgres sql

```
with data as
(
select 'A' as emp_name,'03122022-1' as dated_on
union
select 'A' as emp_name,'03122022-2' as dated_on
union
select 'A' as emp_name,'03122022-3' as dated_on
union
select 'A' as emp_name,'03122022-4' as dated_on
union
select 'A' as emp_name,'03122022-5' as dated_on
union
select 'A' as emp_name,'03122022-6' as dated_on

)
,
data_clean as (
select emp_name,dated_on,
to_date((regexp_split_to_array (dated_on,'-'))[1],'DDMMYYYY') as bill_dated_on,
(regexp_split_to_array (dated_on,'-'))[2] ::int as bill_id
from data)

select emp_name,max(bill_id) from data_clean
where bill_dated_on='20221203'
group by emp_name;

emp_name|max|
--------+---+
A       |  6|
```